# Sharing Audio over bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, bluetooth, share

I want to write a function in my iPad App, which allows me to stream the music choosen on iPad to the connected Game-Interfaces (iPod, iPhone...) via bluetooth. Does anyone knows a simple solution or maybe wants to share some sample code?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something very similar. I have my iphone connecting to multiple devices to stream audio to them, but I want the device that is streaming the audio to also play audio as well.

You can look into the GKSession in the GameKit API and that should give you a good start.
Also maybe openAl, but I think that might be a little overboard. I heard Core Audio has a built in feature for bluetooth devices that are connected to play audio through them but I dont think this goes for iPhone, iPad, iTouch etc....

I have also created my own peer connection interface that allows me to see multiple bluetooth devices that are running my app. I then can click each one and each gets connected. I then I added a test to push a text message to all connected devices for testing. Next I need to find out how to stream audio to the connected apple devices.

If anyone has any info on this I am sure we would both appreciate it.

Comment: Could you share your research, where you found how to do this or any info you found useful? Or even a git repository I can look to?